# Insert 5000 records in sql server 2008 with query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table of employees and their ratings as shown:

```
ID        EmployeeId   RatingHr  RatingMgr   RatingTL  SelfRating     

1           E1           1        1           1        1         
2           E2           3        3           3        3 
3           E3           5        5           5        5 
4           E4           7        7           7        7 
5           E5           9        9           9        9 
6           E6           1        1           1        1         
7           E7           3        3           3        3 
8           E8           5        5           5        5 
9           E9           7        7           7        7 
10          E10          9        9           9        9
.           .            .        .           .        . 
.           .            .        .           .        .
1000        E1000        9        9           9        9
```

I want to insert records upto 1000 like this.
How should I do it.

Comment: create xml of all records and give it to store procedure.so there will be only one call.

Comment: "I want to insert records upto 1000 like this." From where?

Comment: From query by using while loop or something.

Comment: Use a Select Into with a counter CTE

Comment: @Aniket - If you like my answer, pleas upvote :)

Comment: @Aniket - Please see the comments under Mikael's answer. Perhaps you should select his answer instead and upvote mine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into YourTable(ID, EmployeeId, RatingHr, RatingMgr, RatingTL, SelfRating)
select T.N,
       'E'+cast(T.N as varchar(10)),
       ((T.N * 2) - 1) % 10,
       ((T.N * 2) - 1) % 10,
       ((T.N * 2) - 1) % 10,
       ((T.N * 2) - 1) % 10
from  (
      select top(1000) row_number() over(order by 1/0)
      from sys.all_objects as o1, sys.all_objects as o2
      ) as T(N)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a reason why your prefer this approach ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev It is a lot faster to add all rows at once instead of one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I remember that bulk inserts are better, but will find out exactly why. Your answer makes sense. Get all the results with the first `select` and then do a `bulk insert`. Is there a way to measure the difference between our solutions.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev you could just measure the time it takes to execute. Something like this perhaps? http://pastebin.com/UiYnSTZT

Comment: Aha ! Just using `Getdate` and `datediff` before and after each solution. Thank you very much Mikael Eriksson, I like you. I am a very grateful to you for this. You = 90sec. Me = 856sec. In one month, I have learn more at SO than 4 years at almaty university. Chenqui.

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer below. Add the extra columns as needed -

```
declare @start int = 0
declare @end int = 1001
declare @no int = 0
create table ##emps(ID int null, 
EmployeeId varchar(50) null, 
RatingHr int null)
while(@start < @end)
begin 
set @start = @start + 1
set @no = ((@start * 2) - 1) % 10
insert into ##emps(ID, EmployeeId, RatingHr)
values(@start, ('E' + convert(varchar(5), @start)), @no)
end
```

Btw, ##emps is a global temporary table. You can replace it by regular table if you need.